# RESTKit: How to specify no sorting?

Tags: objective-c, restkit

If I don't set the `NSSortDescriptor` on the `NSFetchRequest`, I get the following runtime exception:

```
An instance of NSFetchedResultsController requires a fetch request with sort descriptors
```

I just want the items to be listed in the order they appear in the fetched JSON. Is this possible? I've tried setting the `NSSortDescriptor` to `nil`, but that doesn't help.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must have a sort descriptor, this is a hard requirement of the fetched results controller.

You should add an integer attribute to your entity and create a mapping from the metadata entry for the collection order to that attribute:

```
@metadata.mapping.collectionIndex : YOUR_NEW_ATTRIBUTE
```

Check the docs [here](http://restkit.org/api/latest/Classes/RKMappingOperation.html).